# Is is possible to unit test RavenDB 3.5.x in a Dotnet Core 3.x application?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, ravendb

I'm currently trying to write unit tests for a helper tool to the main application. The main application runs on NETFX 4.7.x and is currently stuck using RavenDB 3.5.9

The helper tool is written in dotnet core 3.1. The RavenDB client works well in dotnet core. However, the RavenDB.Tests.Helpers library ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Tests.Helpers)) seems to be written only for .NET FX.

After adding the project to the dotnet core unit tests project, I see an error saying the package was restored using NETFX 4.6.1. The helper application's unit test project compiles. Predictably, it fails to execute the tests.

Are there are any known ways to get around this limitation? Or would I have to redo the helper application to use NETFX?

Thanks!